# Java char to entire string compare

Tags: java, string, compare

I have an issue with a string compare problem...

lets say: string a = "0123456789ABCDEF" string b = "00CC0G"

how do i loop a java code so i can check string a for match with each letter from string b. While comparing the match, the letter from string b has to go thru the entire loop against string a before deciding if there is a match or not. if a match is found it should check the next letter in string b against string a and so on until the last letter in string b. if no match is found, the function shud exit the loop and return false. otherwise if each letter in string b is a match atleast once with string a, the function shud return true.

Example... the function should return false, because the first 5 letters match but the last one doesnt.

any idea? Thanks

**EDIT**: what i have so far

public boolean checkVal(String b) {

```
// b = "00CC0G";

String a = "0123456789ABCDEF";
String toUC = b.toUpperCase();
char[] cArray = toUC.toCharArray();
char[] vArray = a.toCharArray();
int j = 0;
int m = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <=cArray.length(); i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k <= vArray.length(); k++) {
        if (cArray[k] == vArray[i]) {
            j++;
        }
        else {
            m--;
            break; //loop should exit if there is a non match and function should return false
        }
    }
}

if (j > 0)  return true; //string a matched atleast once with string b
if (m < 0)  return false; //string a alteast has one NO MATCH with string b
```

}

The looping is what getting me confused...

Comment: And... what have you tried so far?

Comment: yeah Jay you should try with your self and then You should post if you've any difficulty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoonfeeding since 2k12.

```
   public static boolean isValid(String a, String b){
    for(char c : b.toCharArray())
        if(!a.contains(""+c))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is basically the direct transcription of the description in the question; it's a shame that there was no sign from the querent of trying to work it out for themselves.

Comment: WOW. such a simple task, i was going thru so much trouble. THANKS! it actually works :) Appreciate the time and effort!